Boost.Beast WebSocket Server - "Read error: The I/O operation has been aborted" on Client Connection
I'm building a WebSocket server using Boost.Asio and Boost.Beast with SSL. The server accepts connections, but I'm encountering an issue where the client disconnects shortly after connecting. The error message I get is:
Read error: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request (Code: 995)

Here’s a breakdown of my setup:

The server uses async_accept to accept new client connections, where each connection is wrapped in an SslWebSocket instance.
A ConnectionManager keeps track of connected clients.
I use async_read to read incoming messages and route them appropriately.
There is also a ping mechanism to keep connections alive.

The server logs the following messages in sequence:

"Starting WebSocket server..."
"Waiting for connections..."
"Connection accepted."
"Attempting to add client..."
"Client added successfully."
After that, I get the read error mentioned above.

Code Sample:
Here’s an excerpt from the do_accept, start_read, and main methods:
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Create io_context and SSL context
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    asio::ssl::context ssl_ctx(asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
    ssl_ctx.set_verify_mode(asio::ssl::verify_none); // Disable SSL verification for testing

    // Define the server endpoint (IP and port)
    tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), 8080);
    auto logger = std::make_shared<FileLogger>(io_context, "server.log"); // Assuming you have a logger class

    // Create the WebSocket server
    auto server = std::make_shared<WebSocketServer>(io_context, ssl_ctx, endpoint, logger);

    // Start the server in a separate thread
    std::thread server_thread([server]() {
        server->start(); // Assuming you have a start method in WebSocketServer
        });

    // Run the io_context in the main thread
    io_context.run();

    // Optionally join the server thread if you want to wait for it
    server_thread.join();

    return 0; // Exit the program when the server is stopped (if ever)
}

void WebSocketServer::start() {
    std::cout << "Starting WebSocket server..." << std::endl;

    try {
        // Start listening for incoming connections
        acceptor_.listen();
        do_accept();  // Begin accepting connections
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error starting server: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
void WebSocketServer::do_accept() {
    std::cout << "Waiting for connections..." << std::endl;
    acceptor_.listen();

    // Use a shared pointer to manage the resolver's lifetime
    auto resolver = std::make_shared<tcp::resolver>(acceptor_.get_executor());

    acceptor_.async_accept(asio::bind_executor(strand_, [this, resolver](beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
        if (!ec) {
            auto ws = std::make_shared<SslWebSocket>(std::move(socket), ssl_ctx_);
            std::cout << "Connection accepted." << std::endl;

            // Attempting to add client immediately
            std::cout << "Attempting to add client..." << std::endl;

            // Add the connection to the manager
            connection_manager_->add_connection(ws);

            // Use a separate post to ensure thread safety
            asio::post(strand_, [this, ws]() {
                // Check if the connection was added successfully
                if (connection_manager_->is_connected(ws)) {
                    std::cout << "Client added successfully." << std::endl;

                    // Start the ping timer
                    asio::steady_timer ping_timer(ws->get_executor(), std::chrono::seconds(30));
                    start_ping(ws, ping_timer, std::chrono::seconds(30));

                    // Start reading messages from the client
                    start_read(ws); // Start reading messages from the client
                } else {
                    std::cout << "Failed to add client." << std::endl;
                    // Close the WebSocket if it was not added
                    ws->async_close(beast::websocket::close_code::normal, [](beast::error_code ec) {
                        if (ec) {
                            std::cerr << "Error closing WebSocket: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Error on accept: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        }

        // Continue accepting new connections
        do_accept();  // This should be called after handling the current connection
    }));
}

void WebSocketServer::start_read(std::shared_ptr<SslWebSocket> ws) {
    auto buffer = std::make_shared<beast::flat_buffer>(); // Use a unique buffer for this read
    ws->async_read(*buffer, [this, ws, buffer](beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (ec) {
            std::cout << "Read error: " << ec.message() << " (Code: " << ec.value() << ")" << std::endl;
            connection_manager_->remove_connection(ws);
            return;
        }

        // Process the received message
        std::string received_message(beast::buffers_to_string(buffer->data()));
        buffer->consume(bytes_transferred); // Clear the buffer after reading

        // Here, you can handle the received message (e.g., route it)
        Message msg = Message::fromJson(received_message); // Assuming the message is a JSON string
        route_message(msg, ws); // Route the message to the appropriate handler

        // Continue reading if the connection is still valid
        if (connection_manager_->is_connected(ws)) {
            start_read(ws); // Continue reading if connection is still valid
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Client has disconnected. Stopping reads." << std::endl;
        }
        });
}

Questions:

What could cause this 995 error code in a Boost.Beast WebSocket server?
Are there specific threading or strand-related configurations that might help resolve this?


Ensuring that the ConnectionManager successfully adds and tracks each client.
Starting a ping-pong mechanism to keep the connection alive.
Confirming that SSL context options are correctly configured.
Verified that the server is correctly listening on the specified endpoint.


Please show a [mre]

better but still not a [mre]

I made it self-contained from the first question code. Adding a Tracer shows where the websocket is destructed:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio  = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
using asio::ip::tcp;

template <typename T>
struct Tracing : T {
    using T::T;
    using T::operator=;

    ~Tracing() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

using SslWebSocket = Tracing<boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::beast::ssl_stream<tcp::socket>>>;

struct Message {
    std::string type;
    std::string data;

    static Message fromJson(std::string const& /*json*/) {
        // Parse the JSON string and return a Message object
        return Message{"type", "data"};
    }
};

struct ConnectionManager {
    void add_connection(std::shared_ptr<SslWebSocket>) {}    // Add the connection to the manager
    void remove_connection(std::shared_ptr<SslWebSocket>) {} // Remove the connection from the manager
    bool is_connected(std::shared_ptr<SslWebSocket>) { return true; } // Check if the connection is still valid
};

struct FileLogger {
    FileLogger(asio::io_context&, std::string const&) {} // Open the log file
    void log(std::string const& message);
};

class WebSocketServer {
  public:
    WebSocketServer(asio::io_context& io_context, asio::ssl::context& ssl_ctx, tcp::endpoint const& endpoint,
                    std::shared_ptr<FileLogger> logger)
        : io_context_(io_context)
        , ssl_ctx_(ssl_ctx)
        , acceptor_(io_context, endpoint)
        , strand_(make_strand(io_context))
        , logger_(logger) //
    {
        connection_manager_ = std::make_shared<ConnectionManager>();
    }

    void start() { do_accept(); }      // Start accepting connections
    void stop() { acceptor_.close(); } // Stop accepting new connections

  private:
    void do_accept();
    void start_read(std::shared_ptr<SslWebSocket> ws);
    void start_ping(std::shared_ptr<SslWebSocket> ws, asio::steady_timer& timer,
                    std::chrono::seconds interval);
    void route_message(Message const& msg, std::shared_ptr<SslWebSocket> ws);

    asio::io_context&                             io_context_;
    asio::ssl::context&                           ssl_ctx_;
    tcp::acceptor                                 acceptor_;
    asio::strand<asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_;
    std::shared_ptr<FileLogger>                   logger_;
    std::shared_ptr<ConnectionManager>            connection_manager_;
};

void WebSocketServer::do_accept() {
    std::cout << "Waiting for connections..." << std::endl;
    acceptor_.listen();

    // Use a shared pointer to manage the resolver's lifetime
    auto resolver = std::make_shared<tcp::resolver>(acceptor_.get_executor());

    acceptor_.async_accept(
        asio::bind_executor(strand_, [this, resolver](beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
            if (!ec) {
                auto ws = std::make_shared<SslWebSocket>(std::move(socket), ssl_ctx_);
                std::cout << "Connection accepted." << std::endl;

                // Attempting to add client immediately
                std::cout << "Attempting to add client..." << std::endl;

                // Add the connection to the manager
                connection_manager_->add_connection(ws);

                // Use a separate post to ensure thread safety
                asio::post(strand_, [this, ws]() {
                    // Check if the connection was added successfully
                    if (connection_manager_->is_connected(ws)) {
                        std::cout << "Client added successfully." << std::endl;

                        // Start the ping timer
                        asio::steady_timer ping_timer(ws->get_executor(), std::chrono::seconds(30));
                        start_ping(ws, ping_timer, std::chrono::seconds(30));

                        // Start reading messages from the client
                        start_read(ws); // Start reading messages from the client
                    } else {
                        std::cout << "Failed to add client." << std::endl;
                        // Close the WebSocket if it was not added
                        ws->async_close(beast::websocket::close_code::normal, [](beast::error_code ec) {
                            if (ec) {
                                std::cerr << "Error closing WebSocket: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                std::cerr << "Error on accept: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            }

            // Continue accepting new connections
            do_accept(); // This should be called after handling the current connection
        }));
}

void WebSocketServer::start_read(std::shared_ptr<SslWebSocket> ws) {
    auto buffer = std::make_shared<beast::flat_buffer>(); // Use a unique buffer for this read
    ws->async_read(*buffer, [this, ws, buffer](beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (ec) {
            std::cout << "Read error: " << ec.message() << " (Code: " << ec.value() << ")" << std::endl;
            connection_manager_->remove_connection(ws);
            return;
        }

        // Process the received message
        std::string received_message(beast::buffers_to_string(buffer->data()));
        buffer->consume(bytes_transferred); // Clear the buffer after reading

        // Here, you can handle the received message (e.g., route it)
        Message msg = Message::fromJson(received_message); // Assuming the message is a JSON string
        route_message(msg, ws);                            // Route the message to the appropriate handler

        // Continue reading if the connection is still valid
        if (connection_manager_->is_connected(ws)) {
            start_read(ws); // Continue reading if connection is still valid
        } else {
            std::cout << "Client has disconnected. Stopping reads." << std::endl;
        }
    });
}

int main() {
    // Create io_context and SSL context
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    asio::ssl::context      ssl_ctx(asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
    ssl_ctx.set_verify_mode(asio::ssl::verify_none); // Disable SSL verification for testing

    // Define the server endpoint (IP and port)
    tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), 8080);
    auto logger = std::make_shared<FileLogger>(io_context, "server.log"); // Assuming you have a logger class

    // Create the WebSocket server
    auto server = std::make_shared<WebSocketServer>(io_context, ssl_ctx, endpoint, logger);

    // Start the server in a separate thread
    std::thread server_thread([server]() {
        server->start(); // Assuming you have a start method in WebSocketServer
        std::cout << "server_thread already exited" << std::endl;
    });

    // Run the io_context in the main thread
    io_context.run();

    // Optionally join the server thread if you want to wait for it
    server_thread.join();
}

// more stubs:

void WebSocketServer::start_ping(std::shared_ptr<SslWebSocket> ws, asio::steady_timer& timer,
                                 std::chrono::seconds interval) {
    timer.async_wait([this, ws, &timer, interval](beast::error_code ec) {
        if (!ec) {
            ws->async_ping({}, [this, ws, &timer, interval](beast::error_code ec) {
                if (ec) {
                    std::cerr << "Ping failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    connection_manager_->remove_connection(ws);
                    return;
                }

                // Restart the timer for the next ping
                start_ping(ws, timer, interval);
            });
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Ping timer error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            connection_manager_->remove_connection(ws);
        }
    });
}

void WebSocketServer::route_message(Message const& msg, std::shared_ptr<SslWebSocket>) {
    // Route the message based on the message type
    if (msg.type == "type1") {
        // Handle type1 message
    } else if (msg.type == "type2") {
        // Handle type2 message
    } else {
        // Unknown message type
    }
}

// FileLogger stubs
void FileLogger::log(std::string const& message) { std::cout << "Logged message: " << message << std::endl; }

Output of a sample run:
Waiting for connections...
server_thread already exited
Connection accepted.
Attempting to add client...
Waiting for connections...
Client added successfully.
Read error: Operation canceled (Code: 125)
Ping timer error: Operation canceled
Waiting for connections...
server_thread already exited
Connection accepted.
Attempting to add client...
Waiting for connections...
Client added successfully.
Read error: Operation canceled (Code: 125)
Ping timer error: Operation canceled
Tracing<boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::beast::ssl_stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::
tcp>>>>::~Tracing() [T = boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::beast::ssl_stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<
boost::asio::ip::tcp>>>]

The debugger will help you see that the problem is that ping_timer is local variable, and its destruction immediate cancels the timer. The causes the timer.async_wait completion to remove the connection.
Other Problems
There's a boatload of other problems.

holding a reference to the local timer object leads to UB
there's no reason to wrap the server start in a thread, since it's async anyways
it's much more sensible to wrap everything related to a connection/session in a session type (e.g. with std::enable_shared_from_this) instead of shuffling around many shared-pointer arguments
keeping shared connections in a connection manager invites resource leaks because they might not be released
in that light,

always let the destructor do the removal. That avoids missing spots, and also duplicating the removal code
better yet, prefer std::weak_ptr to hold on to the session. Then ConnectionManager::is_connected can use weak_ptr::expired() to check whether the connection is still valid


Since ConnectionManager is simply owned by WebSocketServer and not passed in as a dependency, the shared/dynamic allocation adds no value.

I might post a fixed up version if I don't have to spend my time elsewhere soon.
UPDATE
Refactoring to the above description leads to: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa8931128b1afddd
However it revealed another GLARING error: all of the SSL handshake is missing, and so is the Websocket handshake. So adding that too:
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
namespace asio      = boost::asio;
namespace ssl       = asio::ssl;
namespace beast     = boost::beast;
namespace websocket = beast::websocket;
using asio::ip::tcp;

struct FileLogger {
    FileLogger(asio::io_context&, std::string const&) {} // Open the log file
    void log(std::string const& message) { std::cout << "Logged message: " << message << std::endl; }
};

namespace WebSocket {
    struct Message {
        std::string type, data;

        static Message fromJson(std::string const& json) {
            // Parse the JSON string and return a Message object
            std::cout << "Received message: " << quoted(json) << std::endl;
            return Message{"type1", "data"};
        }
    };

    struct Session;
    using Router = std::function<bool(Message const& msg, std::shared_ptr<Session> ws)>;

    struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
        Session(tcp::socket s, std::shared_ptr<FileLogger> logger, ssl::context& ctx, Router router)
            : stream_(std::move(s), ctx), logger_(std::move(logger)), router_(std::move(router)) {}

        void start() {
            std::cout << "Session accepted (" << peer_ << ")" << std::endl;
            do_ssl_handshake(); // no dispatch needed, as session creator will start this
        }

        ~Session() { std::cout << "Session closed (" << peer_ << ")" << std::endl; }

      private:
        using Stream     = websocket::stream<boost::beast::ssl_stream<tcp::socket>>;
        using close_code = websocket::close_code;
        Stream                      stream_;
        tcp::endpoint               peer_{beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).remote_endpoint()};
        std::shared_ptr<FileLogger> logger_;
        asio::steady_timer          ping_timer{stream_.get_executor()};
        Router                      router_;
        beast::flat_buffer          buffer; // Use a unique buffer for this read

        void do_ssl_handshake() {
            stream_.next_layer().async_handshake( //
                Stream::next_layer_type::handshake_type::server,
                [this, self = shared_from_this()](beast::error_code ec) {
                    if (!ec)
                        do_ws_handshake();
                    else
                        std::cerr << "Handshake failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                });
        }

        void do_ws_handshake() {
            stream_.async_accept([this, self = shared_from_this()](beast::error_code ec) {
                if (!ec) {
                    std::cout << "WebSocket handshake successful" << std::endl;
                    timer_loop(std::chrono::seconds(30));
                    read_loop();
                } else {
                    std::cerr << "WebSocket handshake failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                }
            });
        }

        // all private member functions are on the strand of the stream
        void timer_loop(std::chrono::steady_clock::duration interval) {
            ping_timer.expires_after(interval);

            ping_timer.async_wait([=, this, self = shared_from_this()](beast::error_code ec) {
                if (!ec) {
                    stream_.async_ping({}, [=, this](beast::error_code ec) {
                        if (ec) {
                            std::cerr << "Ping failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                            stream_.async_close(close_code::going_away, asio::detached);
                        } else {
                            timer_loop(interval); // Restart the timer for the next ping
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    std::cerr << "Ping timer: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    if (ec != asio::error::operation_aborted)
                        stream_.async_close(close_code::abnormal, asio::detached);
                }
            });
        }

        void read_loop() {
            stream_.async_read( //
                buffer, [this, self = shared_from_this()](beast::error_code const ec, size_t xfr) {
                    if (!ec.failed() && router_) {
                        // Process the received message
                        std::string received_message(beast::buffers_to_string(buffer.data()).substr(0, xfr));
                        buffer.consume(xfr); // Clear the buffer after reading

                        Message msg = Message::fromJson(received_message);

                        if (router_(msg, self))
                            return read_loop(); // early exit
                    }

                    if (ec.failed()) {
                        std::cerr << "IO error " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                        stream_.async_close(close_code::protocol_error, asio::detached);
                    } else if (!router_) {
                        std::cerr << "No router set" << std::endl;
                        stream_.async_close(close_code::policy_error, asio::detached);
                    } else {
                        std::cerr << "Closing" << std::endl;
                        stream_.async_close(close_code::normal, asio::detached);
                    }

                    ping_timer.cancel(); // also cancel the ping timer
                });
        }
    };

    struct SessionManager {
        SessionManager(ssl::context& ctx, Router router) : ssl_ctx_(ctx), router_(std::move(router)) {}

        std::shared_ptr<Session> create(tcp::socket s, std::shared_ptr<FileLogger> logger) {
            garbage_collect();

            auto sess = std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(s), logger, ssl_ctx_, router_);
            sessions_.push_back(sess);
            return sess;
        }

        size_t numberConnected() const { return sessions_.size(); }

      private:
        ssl::context& ssl_ctx_;
        Router        router_;

        void garbage_collect() {
            sessions_.remove_if([](Handle const& h) { return h.expired(); });
        }

        using Handle = std::weak_ptr<Session>;
        std::list<Handle> sessions_;
    };

    class Server {
      public:
        Server(asio::io_context& io_context, ssl::context& ssl_ctx, tcp::endpoint const& endpoint,
               Router router, std::shared_ptr<FileLogger> logger)
            : acceptor_(make_strand(io_context), endpoint)
            , logger_(logger)
            , session_manager_(ssl_ctx, std::move(router)) {}

        void start() {
            /* assuming start is called from the single thread that created the
             * server, no need for strand dispatch
             */
            acceptor_.listen();
            do_accept();
        }

        void stop() {
            dispatch(acceptor_.get_executor(), [this] { // strand dispatch
                acceptor_.cancel();
                acceptor_.close();
            });
        }

      private:
        void do_accept() {
            std::cout << "Waiting for connections..." << std::endl;

            acceptor_.async_accept([this](beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
                if (!ec)
                    session_manager_.create(std::move(s), logger_)->start();
                else
                    std::cerr << "Error on accept: " << ec.message() << std::endl;

                if (ec != asio::error::operation_aborted)
                    do_accept(); // can also be done before creating the session based on `s`

                std::cout << "Active sessions: " << session_manager_.numberConnected() << std::endl;
            });
        };

        tcp::acceptor               acceptor_; // bound to strand
        std::shared_ptr<FileLogger> logger_;
        SessionManager              session_manager_;
    };
} // namespace WebSocket

int main() {
    // Create io_context and SSL context
    asio::io_context ioc;
    ssl::context     ctx(ssl::context::sslv23);
    ctx.use_certificate_file("server.pem", ssl::context::pem);
    ctx.set_password_callback([](std::size_t, ssl::context::password_purpose) { return "test"; });
    ctx.use_private_key_file("server.pem", ssl::context::pem);
    ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_none); // Disable SSL verification for testing

    // Define the server endpoint (IP and port)
    tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), 8080);
    auto logger = std::make_shared<FileLogger>(ioc, "server.log"); // Assuming you have a logger class

    // Create the WebSocket server
    auto router = [](WebSocket::Message const& msg, std::shared_ptr<WebSocket::Session>) -> bool {
        // Route the message based on the message type
        if (msg.type == "type1") {
            return true;
        } else if (msg.type == "type2") {
            return true;
        }
        // Unknown message type
        return false;
    };

    WebSocket::Server server(ioc, ctx, endpoint, router, logger);
    server.start();

    ioc.run();
}



Added a full live demo with all the issues mentioned fixed
